# Hardcoding access token does not work in google spreadsheet api?

Tags: java, google-sheets

Using this example ( https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#creating_a_spreadsheet ), I am able to login and use the Google spreadsheet api using oAuth 1.0 at the moment, because they have a java sample for that.

Here, it gets the access token + secret, and, subsequent calls to the SpreadsheetService work.

But if i want to come back **a day later**, and use the same access token + secret, that should work as well right?

If i do this, however, it gives me an exception:

```
com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Unknown authorization header
```

What am i missing? Do i have to redirect the user to that URL all the time?

My Java code looks as follows:

```
    SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

    GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
    OAuthHmacSha1Signer signer =  new OAuthHmacSha1Signer();
    GoogleOAuthHelper oauthHelper = new GoogleOAuthHelper(signer);
    oauthParameters.setScope(SCOPES);

    oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY); // hardcoded variable
    oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);// hardcoded variable
    oauthParameters.setOAuthTokenSecret(OAUTH_ACCESS_SECRET);// hardcoded variable
    oauthParameters.setOAuthToken(OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN);// hardcoded variable
    service.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters,signer);

    SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the refresh token to get a new access token. The access token does not last long, maybe 1 hour, something like that. The google drive DrEdit tutorial has most of the code for doing the refresh. Was not hard to change the DrEdit code to get a new token. .... (on the other hand, google apps script also has a spreadsheet API)

Comment: thanks, this tutorial gets me going. The oauth dance can be quite hard to debug without a good working example.